# Insert else update & Update else Insert in lookup

Tags: informatica

What is the difference between Insert else update & Update else Insert in lookup transformation. Can anyone, please explain with example

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, there will be no *functional* difference. It's more about the performance - whichever option you choose, the latter is attempted after first operation fails. So it's best to use the option you'd suspect to succeed on first attempt more often.
Say we've expect 80% of updates and 20% of inserts and 10.000 rows:

- With Insert else Update we will end up having 18.000 operations (10k inserts with 8k failed followed by 8k updates)
- With Update else Insert there will be 12k DB operations (10k updates with 2k failed resulting in 2k inserts).

Answer (score -2):

Update else insert effects rows marked for update. When checked, they will be inserted in the cache if they don't exist in the cache.

Insert else update effects rows marked for insert. When checked, they will be updated in the cache if they exist in the cache.